# get ErrorLog value from PHP

Tags: php, apache

How can I know the apache log directory from PHP?. For example, I have a machine where the log path is /var/log/httpd and others with /var/log/apache2 and I don't want to hardcode it or to find the path with tryouts...is it possible to read any constant or php function which gives such information?

thanks in advance!
pablo.

Comment: You should look at your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini theres a variable called error_log

you can get it with ini_get

```
$logpath = ini_get('error_log');
```

now you have the path of the log stored in your variable.

Comment: As a addon, if you need to know the path, use above code and add: print_r($logpath); It will print the path for you.

Comment: I tried before but this variable comes empty, also I've tested ini_get_all() but there is nothing about logs there.

Comment: check if the line is not empty in php.ini